# javascript querySelectorAll() - how to

Tags: javascript

I have this code. Even after the statement

```
curr_attr.value = 'display: block' ;
```

is executed the panel does not become visible. But, it works the on the second time though, it alternates between working and not-working.

```js
function filterEntries() {
    var selectedText = $("#search :selected").text();
    var enteredText = $("#txtSearchValue").val();
    enteredText = enteredText.split(" ").join("");

    var table;
    var allPanels = $(".panel");

    console.log("allPanels.hide(2000); at line number 202");
    allPanels.hide(1000);

    if (selectedText.toLowerCase() === 'band name') {
        if (enteredText === '') {
            // remove filter and show all elements
            console.log("allPanels.show(); at line number 210");
            allPanels.show(1000);
        } else {

            //console.log("allPanels.show(); at line number 215");
            //allPanels.show(1000);

            table = document.querySelectorAll("[data-searchband=" + CSS.escape(enteredText) + "]");

            for (var i = 0; i < table.length; ++i) {
                // print the tag name of the node (DIV, SPAN, etc.)
                var curr_node = table[i];
                console.log(curr_node.tagName);

                // show all the attributes of the node (id, class, etc.)
                for (var j = 0; j < curr_node.attributes.length; ++j) {
                    var curr_attr = curr_node.attributes[j];
                    console.log(curr_attr.name, curr_attr.value);
                    if (curr_attr.name === 'style') {
                        curr_attr.value = 'display: block' ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   else {
        alert("Please select a search criteria");
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <select id="search" class="navbar-inverse small" name="search" onchange="searchFilters()">
            <option value="-1">Search Criteria</option>
            <option value="band">Band Name</option>
            <option value="title">Content Title</option>
         </select>
        &nbsp;
        <input type="text" class="small" id="txtSearchValue" placeholder="Search for...">
        &nbsp;
       <span id="btnSearch" onclick="filterEntries()" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Search</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a loop to find the `style` attribute? Anyway,   I can't tell what you're saying isn't working. Are you saying that `querySelectorAll` sometimes doesn't find any elements?

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoveflow.com/help/mcve/) (because... https://jsfiddle.net/wnoesqj0/)

Comment: What I am saying is the curr_attr.value = 'display: block'; does not work alternatively. The first time around after calling allPanels.hide(); the  curr_attr.value = 'display: block'; gets executed but does not unhide one of the panels. The second time when the button is clicked the unhide works. The third time unhide does not work. The forth time unhide works. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Andreas - have updated the HTML and JS code for the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with hide and show. I had used hide(2000) and show(). After replacing hide(2000) with hide(), it started working. I guess the animation was messing up with the show() or display = block. Now with hide(2000) replaced with hide(), the display = block works perfectly. Thanks all!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `curr_node.style.display = 'block'`.

For example type in the console `document.body.style.display = 'none'` and see the effect.

Comment: That's an alternate way to set the style, but how does it solve the problem described in the question?